# Finding out if values in dataframe increases in tens place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out if the value in my dataframe is increasing in the tens/hundreds place. For example I created a dataframe with a few values, I duplicate the values and shifted them and now i'm able to compare them. But how do i code and find out if the tens place is increasing or if it just increasing by a little, for example 0.02 points.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

data = {'value':['9','10','19','22','31']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['value_copy'] = df['value'].shift(1)
df['Increase'] = np.where(df['value']<df['value_copy'],1,0)
```

output should be in this case:
[nan,1,0,1,1]

Comment: Not sure I understand, but `df['value'].astype(float).diff() >= 10`  ?

Comment: I mean if the value goes up from 9 to 10 and reaches another tens place number.

Comment: Can you attach expected  output  for your example ? I'm guessing in that case, you can just round to tens and then compare.

Comment: what results do you expect?

Comment: The current outcome is [0,0,1,0,1] because it is increasing twice. But im only interested in the values which reach the next tens place. This would be [0,0,1,0,0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, divide by 10, get the `floor`, then compare the successive values (`diff(1)`) to see if the difference is exactly 1:

```
np.floor(df['value'].astype(float).div(10)).diff(1).eq(1).astype(int)
```

If you want a jump to at least the next tens (or more) use `ge` (≥):

```
np.floor(df['value'].astype(float).div(10)).diff(1).ge(1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

NB. if you insist on the NaN:

```
s = np.floor(df['value'].astype(float).div(10)).diff(1)
s.eq(1).astype(int).mask(s.isna())
```

output:

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I changed the values for a better example. I want the values which reach the next tens place compare to the last value. 9-10 true 10-19 false 19-22 true 22-31 true

Comment: @AchillesDay it is what my code is doing, just shifted (it wasn't clear from your initial question). See edit